# Getting "data type mismatch in criteria expression" when I am trying to save date in excel vb form

Tags: vb.net, excel, date-formatting

I have a user form from which I want to save data into  excel, I can save a normal string and integer but when I am trying to save data from Label13(contains date selected from calendar) in below code, it gives  me error as "data type mismatch in criteria expression"

```
Try
Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet
Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim path As String = "D:\Hotel\RoomAvailability.xls"
Dim Sqlq As String
Dim Booked_From As string = Label13.Text
Dim Room_Number As String = 202
MsgBox(Booked_From)
MsgBox(Room_Number)
Sqlq = "Update [Sheet1$] Set [Booked_From] = "
Sqlq = Sqlq & "'" & Booked_From & "'"
Sqlq = Sqlq & " where [Room_Number] ="
Sqlq = Sqlq & "'" & Room_Number & "'"
MsgBox(Sqlq)
MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection( "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Sqlq, MyConnection)

 dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
 MyCommand.Fill(dataSet)
 DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)

 MyConnection.Close()
 Catch ex As Exception
 MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
 End Try
```

Also what should be the format of cell in Excel in which i want to store date from Label13 ?

Comment: How are you getting the date selected from the calendar and populating label 13?

Comment: I am using below code to populate date into LabelPrivate Sub MonthCalendar1_DateSelected(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateSelected
        Label13.Text = MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart
        MonthCalendar1.Hide()